# Why doesn't Intl.NumberFormat work with units in Safari and Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, safari, react-intl

I'm trying to use the example given [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat#Examples) concerning formatting a number.

```js
console.log((16).toLocaleString('en-GB', {
    style: "unit",
    unit: "liter",
    unitDisplay: "long"
}));
```

I tried it in chrome and it works great. However, in Safari as well as Firefox I get the following errors respectively `Error: style must be either "decimal", "percent", or "currency"` and `Error: invalid value "unit" for option style`.

From the docs I figured it should work on all browsers after looking at the browser compatibility. I tried looking for answers, but I can't find anything regarding this issue. Does anyone know why this is or where I could probably find more info?

Comment: javascript interpreters represent millions of lines of code, if you find an error there you can open an error ticket to inform them

Comment: I understand. I was just wondering whether it's a bug or just that it's not supported after all. Can't find any information on it.

Comment: if the same js code gives 2 different results on 2 distinct interpreters, there is a good chance that this is an interpreter bug.

Comment: Unfortunately, we have given up on making a list of all unknown buggs, probably because there are too many!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem comes from the value `unit` of the `style` field.

According to [ECMA-402, 6th edition, June 2019
ECMAScript® 2019 Internationalization API Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/#sec-properties-of-intl-datetimeformat-instances):

> The value of this field must be a record, which must have fields with the names of the three number format styles: "decimal", "percent", and "currency".

According to the [Draft ECMA-402 / February 27, 2020
ECMAScript® 2020 Internationalization API Specification](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-intl-numberformat-constructor):

> The value of this field must be a Record, which must have fields with the names of the four number format styles: "decimal", "percent", "currency", **and "unit"**.

Firefox and Safari are implementing the 6th edition of the ECMA-402 specification and Chrome is implementing the Draft version of this same specification. The draft specification can change at any time and there is no formal guarantees that this new `unit` value will be included in the 7th edition. If you want to be cross-browser compatible and future-proof, you should stick on the 6th edition and wait for the release of the 7th edition before using these new features.

If you want details you can read the [proposition for this new feature](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-unified-intl-numberformat).

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up. I think MDN should clarify this in their docs, because when looking at the browser compatibility section it is kinda misleading.

Comment: [The proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-unified-intl-numberformat) has been updated on March 23, 2020 with this status: "This proposal has been merged into ECMA-402 and is scheduled for the 2020 edition of the specification."

Comment: [See here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_intl_numberformat_numberformat_unit) for this feature's current browser compatibility.

Comment: Can someone explain why I still get the error after fetching Intl.NumberFormat polyfills?